# Covert string to time and sum up in PHP

Tags: php, forms, timestamp

I'm creating reservation system and I'm trying to sum up time string from form values. First two form fields are starting point with hour (9 to 18) and minutes (00 and 30) user chooses e.g 9 and 30.

```
$time = "".$_POST['h'].":".$_POST['min'].":00";
```

Second form field is how long item will be reserved (30min to 3h).

```
<select name="reserved">
<option value="0:30">30 min.</option>
<option value="1:00">1:00 h.</option>
<option value="1:30">1:30 h.</option>
<option value="2:00">2 h.</option>
<option value="2:30">2:30 h.</option>
<option value="3:00">3 h.</option>
</select>
```

So I need to sum up $time and "reserved" dropdown values to get proper summed time 9:30 + 0:30 = 10:00. Hope you understand, thanks for advices. Tried to convert to time stamp and sum it up, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the start time is 9:30 and the reserved time is 0:30, use `strtotime` to get the timestamp of the start time, and add it with total seconds of the reserved time.

```
$a = '9:30';
$b = '0:30';
list($h, $m) = explode(':', $b);
echo date('H:i', strtotime($a) + $h*60*60 + $m*60); // 10:00
```

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you try combining the time as a string and then supplying that to `strtotime()` function? That will give you a timestamp. And from there you can do what ever manipulation you want.

Check docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)